# Indicator functions and measurable sets

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is   Lebesgue measurable and $f(x)\in\{0,1\} $for almost all $x\in[0,1]$.

Do we always have $f $ being represented by some indicator function $\chi_{A} $,   where $A$ is the union of finitely or countably many disjoint measurable subsets of $[0,1]$?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not take $A=\{x:f(x)=1\}$?

Comment: Hi,  what would $A$ look like? Can it be the union of countably many measurable subsets or not?

Comment: If $f$ is measurable then $A$ is.